# Do non-atomic objects have same modification order in all threads? (in absence of data races)

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic, lock-free, memory-model

1.10/6:

> All modifications to a particular atomic object M occur in some particular total order, called the modification
>   order of M.

Do non-atomic objects also have same modification order in all threads? I am interested in properly synchronized cases (in absence of data races, etc).

Comment: Do you mean something like `a = 3; synchronisation_event; b = 5;`?

Comment: No, I am talking about single object. Let say we have some non-atomic counter protected by acquire/release spin-lock (synthetic example), it is incremented by one thread from 0 to 100. Will all other threads see modifications in right total order? like [1,49,88,100] is "right", while [1,49,35,60,100] is wrong. I feel like this is covered only by syncronization itself, but I want to be sure about same modification order...

Comment: @qble: I believe I share your belief, but I don't feel confident enough to post an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have synchronization between all participating threads.

If you have one (or more) thread(s) updating a non-atomic value (with any amount of synchronizing operations among their group) and another thread reading that value (without synchronizing with any updater threads), you are not even guaranteed that you will read one of the values the other threads have stored.

Generally, if one thread **updates** a non-atomic variable and another **accesses** (updates or reads) it without proper synchronization between these two operations, you have a *data race*. A data race causes undefined behavior.

If you "properly synchronize" accesses to a non-atomic variable, you will have a *happens-before* relationship between any modification and any access in another (or of course the same) thread. This includes the relationship between any two modifications.

That happens-before relationship is valid across all threads and induces a total order between modifications. So, yes: properly synchronized use gives you a total modification order (which even is the same for all variables synchronized using the same synchronizing operations).

Comment: "A data race causes undefined behavior." - yes, I know. "That happens-before relationship is valid across all threads and induces a total order between modifications." - yes, I agree with this, all properly synchronized access implies total modification order. Thank you - accepted.

Comment: So, just to summarize - non-atomic access must be syncronized, that implies total ordering. On the other hand, atomic operations need not to be syncronized by "external" means - that why such thing as "same modification order of atomic object" does exist in ISO. Is it right?

Comment: Right. The modification order of atomic variables combined with the right synchronization operations allows to establish a consistent total order of stores and loads for a set of non-atomic objects.

Comment: @JoergB - it's a little trickier than that. Specifically, you only get a consistent **total order** if the associated atomic operations use `memory_order_seq_cst`, i.e., impose **sequential consistency**. That's the default, and nobody who doesn't absolutely have to will do anything else. But it's possible to use more relaxed forms of memory ordering that do not guarantee a total order.

Comment: @PeteBecker thanks for clarifying that here. I wasn't clear enough. I meant to say that you can obtain sequential consistency using acquire/release consistency to build a (single) lock (as per the OPs comment). I should have clarified that of course not all synchronization that is sufficient to avoid data races yields sequential consistency.

Comment: @JoergB - I hadn't noticed the comment.